# Creating a 10-20 Montage (EEG, fNIRS) Figure using R

Tags: r

I have been browsing the interwebs trying to find a reproducible way to create 10-20 Montage Figures (which you regularly see in articles) from EEG and fNIRS publications in R. An example is

[image: 1020-wiki - merged]

Many of the packages that create nice figures are MRI based (brainconn, threeBrain) but these don't seem to allow the labelling of electrodes according to the 10-20 space.

Comment: This is more of a workaround, but you can use the Reticulate package to run MNE-Python from R: https://mne.tools/mne-r/index.html

Comment: Although I'm more familiar with EEGLAB, as far as I can see on their documentation.. the MNE package won't allow for labels to be inserted as shown in my example.

https://mne.tools/stable/auto_tutorials/intro/40_sensor_locations.html#sphx-glr-auto-tutorials-intro-40-sensor-locations-py

Comment: I believe the 10/20 space is supported in MNE (see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58783695/how-can-i-plot-a-montage-in-python-mne-using-a-specified-set-of-eeg-channels and the docs: https://mne.tools/stable/auto_examples/visualization/eeglab_head_sphere.html)